# I a, getting error - Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors

Here is the code.........

```
<?php
include('../inc/php/inc/dbc.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM available_fsv WHERE a_status = '1'";
$result_query = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query)){ 

        $billingid = $row['billingid'];

$query = "UPDATE available_fsv SET b_status = '1' WHERE billingid = '$billingid'";
$result_query = mysql_query($query);
echo $result_query; 
}
?>
```

The error i am getting...........

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\php\fsv_shutdown_cron.php on line 6
```

Database structure is like--

```
____________________________________________________
|   id   |   a_status | b_status    | billingid    |
|--------|------------|-------------|--------------|
|    1   |    1       |     0       |      1       |
|--------|------------|-------------|--------------|
|    2   |    0       |     0       |      12      |
|--------|------------|-------------|--------------|
|    3   |    0       |     0       |      9       |
|--------|------------|-------------|--------------|
|    4   |    1       |     0       |      3       |
|________|____________|_____________|______________|
```

What i wanna do is if a_status is 1 then update b_status to 1.

I am learning php and I know this is a stupid question but please help me. Thanks in advance..  :)

Comment: Are you sure you are already connected to db? Try `echo mysql_error` after you are doing `include`

Comment: Please run this query on phpmyadmin and check results.

Comment: you mess up the `$query` and `$result_query`, they appeared twice in the code, see my answer below

Comment: `UPDATE available_fsv SET b_status='1' WHERE a_status='1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call `mysql_query($query)` returned FALSE, instead of result set, which means that your query had errors in it.  Use the following code to see the error:

```
$result_query = mysql_query ($query);
if ($result_query === FALSE)
{
    echo (mysql_error ());
    die (1);
}
```

Looks like I was wrong.  You really overwrite original value of `$result_query` when you execute your update query.

Answer (score 1):

you mess up the `$query` and `$result_query`, they appeared `twice` in the code

error is on the `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query)){`  line.. here your `$result_query` is nothing but the response of your `update` query..

try this :

```
<?php
 include('../inc/php/inc/dbc.php');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM available_fsv WHERE a_status = '1'";
 $result_query = mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query)){ 
    $billingid = $row['billingid'];
    $update_query = "UPDATE available_fsv SET b_status = '1' WHERE billingid = '$billingid'";
    $update_result_query = mysql_query($update_query);
    echo $update_result_query; 
    echo "<br />";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly update using inline `IF`

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    b_status = IF(a_status = 1, 1 , b_status )
```

if you are executing this, you don't need to communicate on the database twice.

Comment: Probably what he wants, but doesn't do quite the same thing if billingid is duplicated in the table.